Start self-upgrade in the background on Linux
My .NET application runs on Linux (usually a Raspberry Pi) and is installed as a Debian package. Now the application shall be able to upgrade itself when it receives a network command to do so. This is probably a complicated thing because the external upgrade script performs these steps:

download the current Debian package file from the internet (might take a few minutes)
run apt-get install to install the downloaded package file, with all options to not stop and ask any questions
delete the downloaded package file

That upgrade script already exists and works fine when run interactively from the local shell. Now it shall be started by the app itself, non-interactively.
As part of the package scripts, the application service itself will be terminated and later restarted. So the app can't wait for the upgrade to complete because it doesn't live to see it.
If I simply start a new process, I can't wait for it. Will it still continue to run when the starting (parent) process exited? Do I need to start the upgrade script in the background somehow, using command & or systemd-run with some arguments?
This is my simple starting point:
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "/usr/local/bin/upgrade-app.sh",
    CreateNoWindow = true
};
var process = Process.Start(psi);


Will it still continue to run when the starting (parent) process exited? You have all the tools you need to verify this yourself ;)

I'm sceptical how long the child process would continue to run if it does. I can only inspect single cases but don't know the rules behind it.

apt-get install requires superuser privilege.  I hope you don't run your .Net application as root?  In any case, I think you should do the unsurprising thing and just let the admin decide when to apt-get upgrade (many of us use cron jobs so that we download packages when bandwidth is cheapest, ready for installation in the daytime, for example).  Don't mess with established workflows!

It's a headless IoT device. The admin wants to install the update through a button in the app itself, not connect to the VPN, login with SSH and hack in a command. And it's not running as root, but sudo can be configured to let the upgrade script through. Thanks for the advice. I know about the app's environment, I just need to run a command in the background that can stop and restart the app itself.
